# Why don't while loops work with QTimer?

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread

## The Problem

I've been trying to build a buffer so that fast appends to a `QPlainTextEdit` don't cause performance problems.

I've tried using QThread for the buffer to no avail. The QThread version can be [viewed here](https://github.com/daegontaven/AlphaHooks/blob/master/AlphaHooks/widgets/console/stream.py)

A fellow developer has been gracious enough to write me a [simplified version](https://gist.github.com/altendky/f7262e4f5aa5a96b0c5f9815d21021af#file-thread-py) where the buffer can be tested against.

## Code

The actual code appends to a `QPlainTextEdit`, but this is just a short example. The whole repository is also [available here](https://github.com/daegontaven/AlphaHooks/tree/master/AlphaHooks) just in case.

```
import sys
from io import StringIO
from queue import Queue

from PyQt5.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QTimer,
                          pyqtSignal, QObject)


class ObjectSignals(QObject):
    """
    Standard set of pyqtSignals. Useful when
    pyqtSignals is not available is some classes.
    """
    signal_str = pyqtSignal(str)
    signal_int = pyqtSignal(int)
    signal_float = pyqtSignal(float)
    signal_list = pyqtSignal(list)
    signal_tuple = pyqtSignal(tuple)
    signal_dict = pyqtSignal(dict)
    signal_object = pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)


class ConsoleStream(StringIO):
    WRITE_DELAY = 0

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.written = ObjectSignals()

        # Buffer Delay
        self.queue = Queue()
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.pop)
        self.timer.start(self.WRITE_DELAY)

    def write(self, string):
        self.queue.put(string)

    def pop(self):
        """Checks if the queue empty before obtaining the
           oldest item to append to the QPlainTextEdit"""
        if not self.queue.empty():
            data = self.queue.get()
            self.written.signal_str.emit(data)  # Do the appends
            print(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    stream = ConsoleStream()

    # This works
    # for i in range(10000):
    #     stream.write(str(i))

    # This does not
    count = 0
    while True:
        count += 1
        stream.write(str(count)+"\n")
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The loops are not friendly with Qt, since it blocks the mainloop (app.exec_ ()), what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: @I'm trying to build a gui interpreter for Python. I need the buffer since the appends are slowing things down. The while loops actually run inside an [InteractiveConsole instance like so](https://github.com/daegontaven/AlphaHooks/blob/master/AlphaHooks/widgets/console/interpreters/python.py). I know it's possible since spyder-ide does it.

Comment: "I've tried using QThread for the buffer to no avail." What was the problem? Can you give more details about the error and what you wanted to do?

Comment: @Trilarion Well this [issue](https://github.com/daegontaven/AlphaHooks/issues/5) sums it up pretty good.